# Transmission grating in pst-optexp

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

It seems that transmission gratings have not been implemented yet in the `pst-optexp`. Does anyone know whether there exists a workaround?

Comment: write to the PSTricks mailing list and you'll get an answer of the package author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 4.4 of the `pst-optexp` package includes a `\transmissiongrating`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4.1,1.6)
  \pnodes(0,1){A}(2,1){B}(4,0.5){C}
  \transmissiongrating[reverse, gratingcount=9](A)(B)(C){TG}
  \optplane[angle=-10](C)
  \addtopsstyle{Beam}{ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.8, arrowinset=0, arrowscale=1.5}
  \drawbeam[linecolor=black](A){1}
  \addtopsstyle{Beam}{loadbeam, savebeam=false}
  \drawbeam[linecolor=green]{1-2}
  \drawbeam[linecolor=red, beamangle=5]{1-2}
  \drawbeam[linecolor=blue, beamangle=-5]{1-2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]